# SSRS Tablix Row Number into different Tablix

Tags: ssrs-2008

I've got an SSRS report with two tables. In the first table, I've got a row number column, that is calculated based on the RunnningValue for the CountDistinct on the tablix.

What I need, is a row number column in the second table, that begins with the next number after the last number in the first table. So, if table 1 has 15 rows, table 2 should begin at 16. I figure i can do another RunningValue + the max value from the other table, but no idea how to get that Max number into the second table. Is this even possible?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that table 1 and table 2 are grouped on different fields, so just putting the same expression from table 1 into table 2 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I did a CountDistinct on the field the other table was grouped on, and that gave me the correct number.